# browsermob-proxy+selenium with vpn not working on mac but works on windows

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, host, browsermob-proxy

I'm using JMeter with my project jar and trying to open the browser with browsermob-proxy, but it shows `ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED with` my VPN connected on MAC.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeCzc.png)

```
 proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
            proxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
            proxy.start();
            options.setCapability("proxy", ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy));
            proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
```

NOTE-

Mac: I'm only facing this issue when my VPN is connected, otherwise, it works fine.

Windows: Everything is working fine with VPN connected or not.

Comment: What's the 'proxy' in ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy)?

Comment: `BrowserMobProxyServer proxy ;` @pburgr

Comment: Seems (to me) order of commends isn't correct. See https://www.swtestacademy.com/webdriver-browsermob-proxy/

Comment: proxy.setTrustAllServers(true); was required for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add
proxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
Before you start your proxy server. This will solve your problem.